# Sphinx and decorators that I'm unable to modify

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to document some code I've written in Python.  I've used Stuart Gathman's pymilter library in my project, so many of my functions are decorated.  I've seen the questions about decorated functions and Sphinx here on SO, but they do not apply to me as I can't modify the milter library code.

Ideas on how to get around this without having to re-write my Sphinx docs would be great.

Thanks

```
@Milter.noreply
def header( self, name, hval ):
    """
    Processes headers from the incoming message and writes them to a new variable for database storage.
    """
    rgxSubject = re.compile( '^(subject)', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL )
    rgxMessageID = re.compile( '^(message-id)', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL )


    self.fp.write( "%s: %s\n" % ( name, hval ) )
    self.headers.append( "%s: %s\n" % ( name, hval ) )

    if ( rgxSubject.search( name ) ) or ( rgxMessageID.search( name ) ):
        self.log.info( "%s: %s" % ( name, hval ) )
        self.subjMsgId[name] = hval
        if ( rgxSubject.search( name ) ): self.Subject = hval

    return Milter.CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
import functools

def header( self, name, hval ):
   pass
   # ...

header = functools.wraps(header)(Milter.noreply(header))
```

To give an example of what this is doing, consider this decorator and function:

```
>>> def dec(f):
...    def wrap():
...       return f()
...    return wrap
... 
>>> 
>>> def f():
...    """docstring"""
...    print 'hey'
```

A decorator is just a callable that returns a function, so you can call the decorator with the function as an argument and then call the result:

```
>>> dec(f)
<function wrap at 0x10909e758>
>>> dec(f)()
hey
```

But as you've noted, the problem with this is that the `__doc__` and `__name__` variables are not preserved because the decorator didn't use [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
>>> f.__doc__
'docstring'
>>> dec(f).__doc__
>>>
```

So, since you can't modify the original decorator definition, just wrap it up yourself:

```
>>> functools.wraps(f)(dec(f))()
hey
>>> functools.wraps(f)(dec(f)).__doc__
'docstring'
```

You could also define your own decorator that takes a decorator as an argument and wraps up the function properly.